# I defined an equals method, but Hashtable ignores it. Why?

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I defined an equals method, but Hashtable ignores it. Why?

Comment: did you also define `hashCode()`?

Comment: May be you've been unkind to it in the past.

Comment: Copied from [Java IAQ - I defined an equals method, but Hashtable ignores it. Why?](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#equals) by Peter Norvig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure you're using the right collection: you *probably* want HashMap instead. Second, make sure you've defined equals() correctly (equals(Object o)), and also make sure you've implemented a working hashCode().

Answer (score 0):

`HashTable` works by using `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Comment: It uses both. You can define hashCode() as returning a constant, and the map will still work; it just won't be very optimal.

Comment: @Joseph Ottinger Realised this 5 sec after posting and changed :D

Answer (score 0):

As well as overriding `equals` you should also supply a method `hashCode()`

```
      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          // ... 
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          // ....
      }
```